# VS2008 Other project Types -> Database -> Database Project missing in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

VS 2008 has a very simply database script management project " Other project Types -> Database -> Database Project"

I am upgrading to vs2010 and I can't find a suitable uprade for this project. It is upgraded to the new, "better" database project that does more for you but we got the whole team used to working with this type of project, a simple script repository that one can run on a database.

Is there something like this in VS2010?

---

ANSWER:

Well, after further searching, it appears the old style database project is [GONE](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/04/19/requiem-to-the-vs-2003-2005-2008-database-project.aspx) :(

that is very sad indeed, there is no no way I can convert my project to vs2010. Sucks! Shame on you Microsoft for this blooper!